# How to Multi-Process Using Python to Calculate Prime Numbers

Tags: python-3.x, linux, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to calculate prime numbers, and {code 1} works. To try and make it faster, I want to use more cores to calculate prime numbers. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3a+ (linux, quadcore). This code basically takes a CSV file, which starts off with
|index|prime|
|-----|-----|
|     |  0  |
|  0  |  2  |

with this, it reads the file and then continues on to check if the next number is prime (3), by dividing by all previous prime numbers that are less then the number to check (3) 's square root.

{code 1}:

```py
print("Importing Libraries...")
import pandas as pd
import csv
import math

print("Done.\n\n\nReading file...")
file = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/primes.csv", "r")
data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
file.close()

print("Done.\n\n\nConverting to a list")

prime_str = [row[1] for row in data]
print(prime_str.pop(0))

print("Done.\n\n\nConverting list to integer")

primes = list(map(int, prime_str))

print("Done.\n\n\nSetting up counters")

n = len(primes) - 1
N_START = n
# primes = [2]
prime = True
num = primes[-1]
num += 1

print("Done. ", num, n, "\n\n\n")

try:
    while True:
        if prime:
            n += 1
            print("{} is the {}th prime number".format(num, n))
            primes.append(num)
            if n % 75000 == 0:
                primes_df = pd.DataFrame(primes)
                primes_df.to_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/primes.csv")
        prime = True
        index = 0
        num += 1
        num_sqrt = math.floor(math.sqrt(num))
        while primes[index] <= num_sqrt and prime:
            if num % primes[index] == 0:
                prime = False
            index += 1

finally:
    primes_df = pd.DataFrame(primes)
    primes_df.to_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/primes.csv")
    print("\n\n\nCalculated and backed {} prime numbers ({} new prime numbers)".format(n, n - N_START))
```

I have not yet tried to multiproccess, as I could not find any way to do so. I suspect the _thread library might be useful

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Until GIL is removed from python (which may happen soon), you can't get a performance benefit from concurrency in python.   You can invoke separate python processes, but the memory footprint would be quite substantial.   You can look at https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ParallelProgramming.html where C will be doing the heavy lifting.  A concurrency-first language like Go (or Java) would be a better fit for this kind of computationally heavy work.

Comment: @erik258: `multiprocessing` is the workaround for getting CPU-bound parallelism despite the GIL. You can't benefit from *threading* (except in I/O bound, and limited CPU-bound cases where most of the work is done in C extensions with the GIL released), but you absolutely can benefit from parallelism if the work can be split among processes.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Do you know how it can be done though?

Comment: I wouldn't say _{code 1} works_ - it always states that the last number in the input file plus 1 were a prime number.

Comment: @Armali Sorry. It works for all other cases. don't know what is wrong, will do testing.